# Is there any PHP/Java equivalent of the purely file-based MSSQL db of .net?

Tags: c#, java, php, .net, database

Am a big fan of the file-based .mdf db of .net which fits the bill just right in terms of portability and ease of implementation for small/medium projects and independent small-scale modules of larger applications.

So is there a similiar thing in PHP/Java?

Comment: I wonder if SQLLite would fit the bill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try SQLite: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.sqlite.php

> SQLite is not a client library used to connect to a big database
>   server. SQLite is the server. The SQLite library reads and writes
>   directly to and from the database files on disk.

Features of SQLite: http://sqlite.org/features.html